# Enable jmx on tomcat7-maven-plugin

Tags: jmx, catalina, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm want to enable JMX on tomcat7-maven-plugin. How do I pass in CATALINA_OPTS to plugin configuration?

Comment: Where you able to get this working? I'm running into a similar issue where it appears the systemProperties are loaded but I cannot connect to the JMX process

Comment: Added below line to my .profile

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9000 -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"

Comment: You should make your comment an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below line to my .profile

```
   export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9000 -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions (not tested):

- add sys props in MAVEN_OPTS
- or try http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/add-system-properties.html which work for tomcat7 too.

Comment: links fixed have fun! :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to enabled jmxremote.authenticate then use this.

in setenv.sh

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7091 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/usr/tomcat/conf/jmxremote.password \
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/usr/tomcat/conf/jmxremote.access"
```

vi jmxremote.access file

```
monitor   readonly
admin     readwrite \
              create javax.management.monitor.*,javax.management.timer.* \
              unregister
```

vi jmxremote.password file

```
monitor pass1
admin pass2
```

change permission

```
sudo chown tomcat7:tomcat7 /usr/tomcat/conf/jmxremote.*
sudo chmod 0600 /usr/tomcat/conf/jmxremote.*
```

Controlling the Ports
we need to add jmx listener 
 /usr/tomcat/conf/server.xml file like this:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
  rmiRegistryPortPlatform="7091" rmiServerPortPlatform="7091" />
```

add jmx jar file inside tomcat lib:/usr/tomcat/lib/.

```
The jar we are looking for is called catalina-jmx-remote.jar.
```

Restart tomcat then try to connect using jconsole or jvisualvm

```
reference :
 1. https://blog.markshead.com/1129/connecting-visual-vm-to-tomcat-7/

2.https://geekflare.com/enable-jmx-tomcat-to-monitor-administer/#:~:text=JMX%20(Java%20Management%20Extension)%20is,Classes%2C%20and%20configure%20various%20MBeans.
```